# Looping over column names like DF$j

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, rows

I have the following data frame:

```
    ID  A1  A2  A3    A4     B1      B2      B3      B4   
1  ID1   1   2   1     1      1       1       2       2
2  ID2   2   2   1     1      2      NA       2       1
3  ID3   2   2   1     2      1       1      NA       2          
4  ID4   1   1   1     1      1      NA      NA       2         
5  ID5   2   2   1     1     NA      NA       2      NA       
6  ID6   1   1   1     1      2       2       2       2
```

I want to extract rows from the data frame meeting specific conditions for each combination of A and B. These are the conditions:

- PP: value 2 present in A-type column + value 2 present in B-type column
- PA: value 2 present in A-type column + value 1 present in B-type column
- AP: value 1 present in A-type column + value 2 present in B-type column
- AA: value 1 present in A-type column + value 1 present in B-type column

This is what I wrote:

```
A <- colnames(dataframe)[2:5]
# A = A1, A2, A3 and A4
B <- colnames(dataframe)[6:9] 
# B = B1, B2, B3 and B4

for (a in A) {  
   for (b in B) {
         PP <- dataframe[dataframe$a=='2' & dataframe$b=='2' , ]
         PA <- dataframe[dataframe$a=='2' & dataframe$b=='1' , ]
         AP <- dataframe[dataframe$a=='1' & dataframe$b=='2' , ]
         AA <- dataframe[dataframe$a=='1' & dataframe$b=='1' , ]
        print(head(PP)) #to have a preview
    }
 }
```

However the new data frames are empty and I don't understand why. 
Ideally, **the first for loop** (with a=A1 and b=B1) would therefore output:

PP:

```
     ID  A1  A2  A3  A4  B1  B2  B3  B4
 2  ID2   2   2   1   1   2  NA   2   1
```

PA:

```
    ID  A1  A2  A3  A4  B1  B2  B3  B4
3  ID3   2   2   1   2   1   1  NA   2
```

AP:

```
    ID  A1  A2  A3  A4  B1  B2  B3  B4
6  ID6   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2
```

AA:

```
    ID  A1  A2  A3  A4  B1  B2  B3  B4
1  ID1   1   2   1   1   1   1   2   2
```

I hope someone can help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dollar sign extraction is creating a problem. It is not meant for passing of variables as in `dataframe$a`. Because `a` is not the actual name. You are trying to pass the variable name on to it. But that operator will look for the literal `a` column and not find it. Try `dataframe[,a]`